# Datameer installation failure

Tags: hadoop, analytics

I was trying to install the trail version of Datameer for RHEL which comes in form of rpm package.
The install was done properly but when I started the services, i got the below error:
    [root@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx ~]# /etc/init.d/das-conductor start
    find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
    find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
    find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
    find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
Found JAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin/java in JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67
Java 7 found
DeployMode: trial
DAS Options:
Java native libraries: /opt/datameer/Datameer-5.5.0-apache-1.0.3/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
Starting jetty using port 8080
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
Starting Jetty: STARTED Jetty Mon May 18 04:02:03 EDT 2015

Comment: logs for datameer /opt/datameer/Datameer-5.5.0-apache-1.0.3/logs/conductor.log, I checked                            "Failed to initialize spring context: Error creating bean with name 'v' defined in file [/opt/datameer/Datameer-5.5.0-apache-1.0.3/webapps/conductor/WEB-INF/classes/datameer/dap/common/license/v.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [datameer.dap.common.license.v]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to store a new product ID.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue. I think you are starting up Datameer as root user. 
After installation of Datameer, there is a user 'datameer'created. You need to switch to that user and run the startup under that user account.